# What is the php_binary serialization handler?

Tags: php, serialization, igbinary

When I do phpinfo() or php -i from the CLI, I get the following output:

```
session

Registered save handlers => files user sqlite memcached
Registered serializer handlers => php php_binary wddx
```

I was not aware that PHP serialization supported a binary format, and there does not appear to be anything in the documentation about it.

I was going to use [**igbinary**](http://opensource.dynamoid.com/) for session serialization to a memcached server, so I'm wondering how *php_binary* compares.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`igbinary` <sup>**PHP extension**</sup>](https://github.com/igbinary/igbinary) does offer a new session serialize/deserialize handler that differs from PHP's own implementations, namely `php` and `php_binary`.

To answer your question: **These handlers do not compare at all, they are totally different.** The differences *igbinary* introduces are documented within the projects readme.

I assume you're asking the question because you found the word *binary* within the two: ig*binary* and php_*binary*. However that's not saying much. Compare the `php` with the `php_binary` handler first:

The `php_binary` session serialize/deserialize handler is nearly identical with the default `php` handler. They differ only how the variable names that are within the session are encoded.

`php_binary` will prefix all session variable names with the binary length of the name. While with `php` each variable name has a suffix of the `|` character (`\x7C`, decimal `124`). From what I know, the serialization of the variable's values does not differ at all.

So the serialization of values is identical between the `php` and `php_binary` handler.

So next to the little difference in pre-/suffix of session variable names, the question actually asks about how does `igbinary` compare with php serialization (which is used in the session data). Those differences are outlined in the [`igbinary` readme](https://github.com/igbinary/igbinary#readme). It fairly well describes what's done and why.

If you like to use `igbinary` serialization as well for serialize/unserialize, the extension offers two replacement functions:

`igbinary_serialize` and `igbinary_unserialize` - used like their php cousins.

If you are concerned about some specifics of the differences, please ask.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! No, I'm pretty clear on how igbinary works, I just couldn't find any information on php_binary when I googled it.

Comment: @Toxikman: Okay, fine then. Most documentation is within "source" :). Both, the `php` and `pbp_binary` formats are not much described in the PHP Manual. You can always look into the C sourcecode and/or reverse engineer the formats.

Comment: Yeah, but that would have taken be 10 times longer than googling the answer, and then by posting a question on StackOverflow about it, and thanks to you, the answer is now readily available for anyone to find on the internets. :-)